# I can't get the zsh-theme to update all the inner shell scripting with each "return" on the terminal

Tags: terminal, zsh

Here is my new oh-my-zsh zsh-theme, updated with an escape character before each code block within $()'s which allows it to update every time the prompt is displayed (works with `setopt prompt_subst`:

```
PROMPT="%F{yellow}%n%F{white}@%F{green}%M %F{cyan}%j %F{white}\$(curl -s https://api.myip.com | jq .ip -r) %F{green}%2c%F{cyan} [%f "
RPROMPT="\$(git_prompt_info) %F{cyan}] %F{red}\$(top -l 1 | grep 'Load Avg' | awk '{print $3, $4, $5}' | tr -d , | awk '{print $2}')[\$(sysctl hw.ncpu | grep -o -E '[1-9]+')] @ \$(top -l 1 | grep 'CPU usage:' | awk '{print $3, $5, $7}' | tr -d , | awk '{print $3,"%%"}') idle %F{green}%W %* %F{yellow}%D{%p}%f"

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="%F{yellow}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%f"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY=" %F{red}*%f"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN=""
```

It will dynamically change the date and time, the IP address, and the git_prompt_info, every time I press return, but the shell scripting like `\$(top -l 1 | grep 'Load Avg' | awk '{print $3, $4, $5}' | tr -d , | awk '{print $2}')` does not update every time I press "return", it gives me an error instead:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    {print >>>  , <<<
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

What's going on here?

Comment: You assign `RPROMPT` from a double-quoted-string. This means that `$1` inside will be replaced by the shell. You would have to escape the $, i.e. write  `\$1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
setopt prompt_subst
```

Enable `prompt_subst` in your zshrc or other file sourced by your shell to make zsh re-evaluate your PS1 variable on each prompt appearance.

Comment: I tried putting ```setopt prompt_subst``` into my .zshrc file. Nothing seemed to change. I notice you said ```PS1``` as opposed to ```PROMPT``` and ```RPROMPT```. What's the ```PS1``` equivalent of the ```RPROMPT```?

Comment: I updated my question to concern the "disobeying" evaluation of ```$( )```'s. - after I successfully put ```setopt prompt_subst``` and the escape character ```\``` before each ```$( )```.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem boils down to an assignment similar to this one:

```
 rp="\$(awk '{print $3, $5, $7}')"
```

If you try this and do a `echo $rp` afterwards, you see that the awk command indeed is broken. The reason is the initial backslash: Because of this, the `$(....)` construct does not represent a new scope and we are inside the (outer) double quotes. Therefore the shell substitutes the `$`-variables.

You have two possibilities:

(1) Escape the $

```
 rp="\$(awk '{print \$3, \$5, \$7}')"
```

(2) Use single quotes for the assignment. Of course this means that you can't have single quotes inside. Example:

```
rp='$(awk "{print $3, $5, $7}")'
```